# MongoDB Get Average of each Filed-Child

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am using javascript - mongoose. (beginner)
Trying to calculate average of 'timeSpend' for each fields

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a2cca1c44ac67e8d5b8d2ff"),
    "total" : {
        "timeSpend" : "20"
    },
    "name_1" : {
        "timeSpend" : 9,
        "test" : "fail"
    },
    "name_2" : {
        "timeSpend" : "11",
        "test" : "fail"
    },
    "name_3" : {
        "timeSpend" : "8",
        "test" : "fail"
    }
    "__v" : 0
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a2cca1c44ac67e8d5b8d2ff"),
    "total" : {
        "timeSpend" : "10"
    },
    "name_1" : {
        "timeSpend" : 10,
        "test" : "fail"
    },
    "name_2" : {
        "timeSpend" : "5",
        "test" : "fail"
    },
    "name_3" : {
        "timeSpend" : "2",
        "test" : "fail"
    }
    "__v" : 0
}
```

.... more documents...(every 10 minutes, new document will be saved)

I am trying to calculate average 'timeSpend' for each fields 
Example :

```
{
total : 15,
name_1 : 9.5,
name_2 : 8,
name_3 : 5
}
```

I tried

```
(mongoose Schema).find({}).select('name_1' : 1, '_id':0)
```

then calculate average using loop, but I think it will be too expensive computing since document will be updated every 10 minutes (have to update average every 10 mins)

Comment: No averages will work the way I think you seek if the data is strings, e.g. "timeSpend" : "11".   Make sure your data is numeric -- in fact, make sure it is either an int or a float (don't need decimal here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that with a simple mongodb *aggregation*.

You basically have to `group by null` to get one document in the end, and use the `$avg` [aggregation operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) to get all averages.

Following would work

```
collection.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        total: {
            $avg: "$total.timeSpend"
        },
        name_1: {
            $avg: "$name_1.timeSpend"
        },
        name_2: {
            $avg: "$name_2.timeSpend"
        },
        name_3: {
            $avg: "$name_3.timeSpend"
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to change Schema with 'Float' then everything was working well :)